# Why do liquids vaporise spontaneously at temperatures below boiling point despite ∆G being positive?

Tags: thermodynamics

We say that for the equilibrium 
$$\ce{A(l)<=>A(g)}$$ the ∆G is zero at its boiling point (the thermodynamic definition of boiling point), and becomes positive at temperatures below the boiling point. However every liquid has a characteristic vapour pressure at all temperatures. How does this happen even though the ∆G has become positive thus the reaction has lost spontaneity?

Comment: If a reaction has a positive $\mathrm{\Delta G}$ does that mean no products whatsoever can be formed? Similarly, if vaporization below the boiling point has a positive $\mathrm{\Delta G}$, does that mean no liquid at all can vaporize? Recall the relation between $\mathrm{\Delta G}$ and the equilibrium constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two considerations about why liquids evaporate but only one of them has to do with the Gibbs free energy of vaporisation.

There is an equilibrium (heavily biased in favour of the liquid not the vapour) at temperatures well below the boiling point. In equilibrium (which is what the ΔG measures) there is enough thermal energy to put a small amount of liquid into the vapour phase but most liquid will remain liquid. This is the correct analysis in a closed vessel. The liquid doesn't *continue* to evaporate once the equilibrium is reached.

But, often, you don't observe liquids in *closed* vessels. This explains why the liquid *continues* to evaporate. The point is that, when the vapour can be removed from the vessel containing the liquid, the normal equilibrium is not established and the liquid can slowly evaporate (at least as long as the surrounding environment has a lower vapour pressure for the liquid than the equilibrium vapour pressure).

In open systems the simple thermodynamic numbers don't correctly describe the long term behaviour because equilibrium isn't what happens.

If you think about what is happening at the molecular level this is easier to understand. Energy is not *evenly* distributed among the molecules of the liquid. *On average* the molecules don't have enough energy to go from liquid to vapour, but *some* of the molecules have more energy than others. So *some* of them have enough energy to escape the liquid phase. And the energy will distribute among the vapour molecules leaving some with so little that they condense back to liquid.

Overall equilibrium is established when the number of low energy vapour molecules condensing is equal to the number of high energy liquid molecules evaporating. Just because there isn't enough energy to boil *all* the liquid doesn't mean *some* of the molecules can't become vapour spontaneously.

Answer (score 1):

Start with a closed container with a quantity of liquid water, and no vapor. Maintain the container at room temperature. What will happen? If the temperature does not change, the overall Gibbs free energy will not change in equilibrium. Now, $G = H - TS$, and at constant temperature $\Delta G = \Delta H - T\Delta S$.

Converting liquid (take as the reference state) to vapor costs enthalpy, the $\Delta H$. But, by allowing vapor to occupy the empty space in the container you have gained a great deal of entropy, $\Delta S$. The first water molecule to go in to the vapor gains a huge amount of entropy - it has the entire volume to roam around in - overwhelming any enthalpy required. The reaction of liquid -> vapor is, in fact, highly spontaneous because of this! But, the next little bit of vapor gets a smaller entropy gain - there is already vapor occupying the head space in the closed vessel. And the next little bit gets even less entropy. Yet, it keeps costing the same amount of enthalpy to convert the liquid to vapor.

As more and more liquid goes in to the vapor phase, the additional entropy gain decreases, while the enthalpy cost remains the same. Eventually the reaction reaches an equilibrium point when $\Delta G = 0 = \Delta H - T \Delta S$ for the overall reaction. The $\Delta H$ is the total enthalpy required to make the equilibrium vapor concentration, and the $\Delta S$ is the total entropy gained by doing so. You have converted $x$ moles of liquid in to vapor, and it is now in equilibrium with the remaining $y$ moles of liquid.

Perhaps that gives you a better perspective.

Answer (score 0):

$\Delta G$ is zero at all temperatures and pressures at which the vapor and liquid are at equilibrium with one another (i.e., all points along the vapor pressure curve), and not just at the atmospheric boiling point.

Comment: Then that has to mean that vaporisation can never be spontaneous because negative ∆G is the condition of spontaneity which is not being met by your arguement.

Comment: In evaporation of, say, water into a room, the partial pressure of the water vapor in the room air (away from the interface) will be lower than the equilibrium vapor pressure.  So the $\Delta G$ in going from the liquid to the partial pressure in the room will be negative.  At the interface, the partial pressure of the water vapor will be only slightly lower than the equilibrium vapor pressure, so evaporation can still occur.  The transport process involved is diffusion of the water vapor from the interface to the bulk air.

Comment: You wrote that ∆G of vaporisation will be negative in going from the liquid to the room. That is exactly my question: isnt the ∆G positive at temperatures below boiling point, and ∆G being the criteria for spontaneity, shouldnt the reaction lose its spontaneity at temperatures below the boiling point. Kindly answer my question directly, and dont take it in circles. No offence.

Comment: **Inital state**: liquid water at temperature T, **Final state**: water vapor in room air at partial pressure p < $p_{sat}(T)$ and temperature T. $ΔG=RT\ln⁡(p/p_{sat}(T))$<0

Comment: Where does it say that $\Delta G$ is positive at temperatures below the atmospheric boiling point in going from saturated liquid to saturated vapor?  Please provide a reference.

Comment: If you don't believe that the gibbs free energy of the saturated liquid is equal to the gibbs free energy of the saturated vapor at all points along the vapor pressure curve, get yourself a set of steam tables, which gives the values of v,h, and s for both the saturated liquid and the saturated vapor along the curve, and calculate g = h - Ts for both the saturated liquid and the saturated vapor at a selection of temperatures, and compare the values you get.

Answer (score 0):

Before diving deep into thermodynamics, make several thought experiments.

1. Open flask with liquid at a room temperature
2. Closed flask with a liquid at a room temperature
3. Ideally thermally insulated closed flask with liquid, starting at room temperature

The vapor pressure corresponds to the equilibrium between liquid and it's vapor (presumably in air). Alternatively, you can think of the chemical potential of the substance in both phases, which should be equal in equilibrium.

Comment: Please can you explain this through Gibb's free energy.

Comment: For the Gibbs energy of multiphase system equilibrium see e.g. http://pruffle.mit.edu/3.00/Lecture_25_web/node2.html